# do something based on referrer URL in php

Tags: php, redirect

I have this code and it works well

```
<?php
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'example.com')){
  echo 'yes'; 
  } else {
    echo 'no';
  }

?>
```

the question is
How do I get yes if the visit is from example2.com also

I tried this but it is not working

```
<?php
    if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'example.com' or 'example2.com')){
      echo 'yes'; 
      } else {
        echo 'no';
      }

    ?>
```

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to create an array of allowed values, and use a loop. Create a Boolean value which states if the user is coming from an allowed site, set it to false as default. While looping through the allowed sites, change this Boolean value to true if the referrer matches any of the allowed sites.

```
$allowed_sites = ['example.com', 'example2.com'];

$referrer_is_allowed = false;

foreach($allowed_sites as $url) {
    if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $url)) {
        $referrer_is_allowed = true;
    }
}

echo $referrer_is_allowed ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Keep in mind, this doesn't guarantee that any certain user actually came from the `HTTP_REFERER` that you are checking against, for a couple of reasons.

1. `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is easily spoofed and can't really be trusted for security.
2. A referer such as `site_not_allowed.com/example.com` would still pass this check.

You can protect yourself from the second problem at least by checking to see if the referrer website *starts with* an allowed site, like this:

```
foreach($allowed_sites as $url) {
    $referrer = str_replace(['http://', 'https://'], ['',''], $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    if(substr($referrer, 0, strlen($url)) === $url) {
        $referrer_is_allowed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works well thank you :)
What if i want to replace echo with include?

Comment: @Farouk You could easily check if the value is true and then do an include. `if($referrer_is_allowed) { include(FILE_TO_INCLUDE); }` - Just make sure you put that code _after_ the `foreach()` loop.